# New in html, why background image not cover "welcome" text

Tags: html, css

I need the background image to cover the entire length of my website.

However, at the moment it gets cut off midway through. The width is perfect and I cannot repeat the image.

I tried background-size:100%",height:100% as well, but it didn't help.

```js
 function search() {
              var search_input = document.getElementById("searchbox").value; // value of search box
              var option = document.getElementById("option").value; //value of select
    
              window.open('http://webpac.kdu.edu.my/search/query?match_1=MUST&field_1=' + option + '&term_1=' + search_input + '&sort=dateNewest&theme=kdu', '_blank'); //proceed with search
            }
```

```css
 body,
          html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
          }
```

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <div class="bg-image"></div>
        <div class="bg-text">
          <h2 style="font-size:30px">Quick Search:</h2>
          <div id="mysearch">
            <form action="" onsubmit="return false">
              <select name="field_1" id="option">
                <option value="t" selected="selected">Title</option>
                <option value="a">Author</option>
                <option value="s">Subject</option>
                <option value="call_number">Call Number</option>
                <option value="p">Publisher</option>
              </select>
              <input type="text" name="term_1" size="38" maxlength="50" value="" id="searchbox" placeholder="Please enter a search term.."><br />
              <button type="submit" onclick=search()><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              <button type="reset"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    
    </html>
```

[Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2w6L5kg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set background to body not to wrapper or parent div like this,

```css
#welcome{
  background-color:white;
}
.background-image {
    z-index:-1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-image:URL(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/photographer.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image"></div>
<div id="welcome">
  <center><h1>Welcome</h1></center>
</div>
```

- `background-size`
  property specifies the size of the background images.
- `background-repeat`
  property sets if/how a background image will be repeated.

As you want to add b blur effect on background-image then you have to create an other div and set background image to it and set it's `z-index` to negative to make sure it will be on the back of everything.
If you add blur effect on body then other content also get that blue property to avoid that make another div. I have just done it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Could you help me to point out which part should I place for blur effect on the background image?

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Could you help me to point out which part should I place for blur effect on the background image? because the current blur setting on the background setting on the css not working anymore..

Comment: @amein answered check it out, Sorry for late edit I was busy at that moments

Answer (score 0):

use

```
background-size: cover;
```

update .bg-image

```
.bg-image {
    background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/photographer.jpg);
    filter: blur(2px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change background-size to cover:

```
  .bg-image {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/photographer.jpg");

    /* Add the blur effect */
    filter: blur(2px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    /*  background-position: center;*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/2fbaym0w/2/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

**Cover**:

```
 Scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image. If the 
 proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either 
 vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.
```